I am trying using stripe checkout as part of my flask web app, I can't split a payment to multiple connect accounts
I think it may be a syntax error but I am trying to distribute one payment to multiple stripe connect accounts whose stripe keys I have stored.
def redirect_stripe_teams(price, recipient_ids,total_amount):

    num_recipients = len(recipient_ids)
    amount_per_recipient = total_amount / num_recipients

    transfer_data = []
    for x in range (0,len(recipient_ids)):
        transfer_data.append({"account":recipient_ids[x],"amount":amount_per_recipient})

    session =stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        mode="payment",
        line_items=[{"price": price.id, "quantity": 1}],
        payment_intent_data={
            "application_fee_amount": 123,
            "transfer_group": transfer_data,
            
            },
        
    success_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000",
    cancel_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000",
    )
    
    return (session)

recipient_ids is a list of the stripe keys.
I have tested what transfer_data looks like with print statements and it looks correct : [{'account': 'acct_1PDTZn3Ub4dNDDpr', 'amount': 1000.0}, {'account': 'acct_1PDTcV4F3YPI18MY', 'amount': 1000.0}]
I have functionality in my web app already to send to one recipient so I know that price is not the issue. Any idea what could be preventing it from going through.
I have tried multiple ways of formatting it but i keep getting these kind of errors :
stripe._error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_HyihEeFw0yaPd0: Invalid string: {:"0"=>{:account=>"acct_1PDTZn3Ub4dNDDpr", :amount=>"1000.0"}, :"1"=>{:account=>"acct_1PDTcV4F3YPI18MY", :amount=>"1000.0"}}
And this one even though the formatting looks correct:
stripe._error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_M9OICq5dr3NYMi: Received unknown parameters: 0, 1
I have also tried changing transfer_group to transfer_data on each test and it still doesnt help.

transfer_data cannot be used to transfer to multiple accounts - just one.
transfer_data={
   'destination':'acct_xyz',
   'amount':123
}

If you want to transfer a single charge to multiple accounts, it's possible, but requires you to create Transfers sequentially, following the Separate Charges and Transfers directive:
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted&lang=python#transfer-availability
stripe.Transfer.create(
  amount=1000,
  currency="usd",
  source_transaction='{{CHARGE_ID}}',
  destination='acct_1PDTZn3Ub4dNDDpr'
)
stripe.Transfer.create(
  amount=1000,
  currency="usd",
  source_transaction='{{CHARGE_ID}}',
  destination='acct_1PDTcV4F3YPI18MY'
)

You need this source_transaction=CHARGE_ID if the funds for the charge are still pending. You can get the Charge ID from the charge.succeeded event or by getting the Checkout session's downstream Payment Intent's latest_charge.

Thanks that makes a lot of sense. I'm assuming this is still able to be automated. Because I am just in development I have not set up webhooks yet, is  "getting the Checkout session's downstream Payment Intent's latest_charge." possible without webhooks, and if so how would I do that. Thanks again

Checkout in general is designed with webhooks in mind, but this is still possible without them. Poll the Checkout session until its status is completed, then look at the payment_intent attribute and retrieve the Payment Intent by that id. You'll find the latest_charge (assuming your account is set with an API version that isn't too old.
